# Cannot Return out of SetInterval

Tags: javascript, php

I'm having an issue where I cannot return out of this setInterval. This function makes an Ajax call to a PHP file. If the data returned is useful it sets a global variable as the data then it should return and stop calling that PHP file. The problem I currently have is that it won't stop running even after it gets useful data. The return seems to have no effect. Maybe I just need another set of eyes on this.

```
setInterval(function() {

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      if (data != 'None') {
        url = data;
        document.getElementById("disableddesktop").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("download").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("enableddesktopscan").style.display = "block";

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
          data: {
            plan: document.getElementById("plan").value,
            country: document.getElementById("firstcountry").value
          },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            numberoforders = data;
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data;
          }
        });

        return;
      }
    }
  });
}, 9000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to `clearInterval` instead of `return`:

```
var interval= setInterval(function(){
  clearInterval(interval); //clear interval
}, 9000)
```

> **interval** is the identifier of the repeated action you want to cancel. This ID is returned from setInterval().

So in your case it should be:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {    
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      if (data != 'None') {
        url = data;
        document.getElementById("disableddesktop").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("download").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("enableddesktopscan").style.display = "block";

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
          data: {
            plan: document.getElementById("plan").value,
            country: document.getElementById("firstcountry").value
          },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            numberoforders = data;
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data;
          }
        });

        clearInterval(interval); //clear interval      
      }
    }
  });
}, 9000);
```

> As mplungjan said its not a good idea to use `setInterval` with AJAX
>   instead use `setTimeout`

Comment: Thanks. I think my main mistake was thinking that setInterval was a loop that I could just return out of. I'll look into using setTimeout. I'm sure there are many ways to make this better but for now working is good enough lol.

Answer (score 0):

To stop setInterval, use a variable and clearInterval:

```
var tId = setInterval();
clearInterval(tId)
```

HOWEVER it is not a great idea to use setInterval AND Ajax.

Instead do this:

```
function getData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
    success: function(data) {
      // alert(data); // NEVER alert in an setInterval or setTimeout
      if (data != 'None') {
        url = data;
        document.getElementById("disableddesktop").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("download").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("enableddesktopscan").style.display = "block";

        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'www.example.com/test.php',
          data: {
            plan: document.getElementById("plan").value,
            country: document.getElementById("firstcountry").value
          },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            numberoforders = data;
            document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = data;
          }
        });
      }
      else setTimeout(getData,9000); 
    }
  });
}
```